# Kafka streams API sample KStream cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I am working thru this Kafka streams tutorial

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/tutorial

on a Centos 7 machine running JRE 8+ and Kafka 0.11.0.1

This is the line that throws the compile error

```
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");
```

Trying to compile the LineSplit example I get a Java exception

```
KStream cannot be resolved to a type
```

Being a Java noob, I am not sure how to resolve this. Double checked import declarations and even copy-pasted the sample in vain.

Any leads on how to resolve this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read a tutorial about Java. (Also please edit your question to include the whole code and how you compile it.)

You need to make sure to

- import all required classes in your code
- provide the corresponding libraries to the compiler

I would recommend to use an IDEA (like Intellij or Eclipse) and use a build tool like maven or gradle.

This tutorial shows how to set up a maven project for your Kafka Streams project: http://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/tutorial

Comment: First off, thank you for being polite to a noob. I sincerely appreciate it. An IDE probably would have picked this up easily, but I am using vi on centos and Maven to build the project. My perplexity stemmed from assuming that the code in the tutorial was perfect and self contained. I had setup maven as described in the link. Didnt realize I had to "import classes" instead of just package names into my project. Got it working now. I vote to delete the question.

Comment: No worries. You can check out working examples in our examples repo: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: Also, you should be able to delete your own question if you want -- but don't think it's required.